# Connection .Then is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

when I was trying to make a StateManager.js file for a discord bot I got a error where when I try to start the discord bot I get an error of *.then((connection) => this.connection = connection)
^
TypeError: connection.then is not a function*, is there any fix to this? the connection is to connect to a database for a discord bot using separate files, not having it in the index.js file.

```
const { EventEmitter } = require('events');
const connection = require('../../database/db');

class StateManager extends EventEmitter{
    constructor (opts){
        super(opts);
        connection
        .then((connection) => this.connection = connection)
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        



    }
}

module.exports = new StateManager();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that "connection" is supposed to return a promise, you first have to call the connection method to get access to the promise.

```js
class StateManager extends EventEmitter{
    constructor (opts){
        super(opts);
        connection()
        .then((connection) => this.connection = connection)
            .catch(err => console.log(err));

    }
}
```